# из секунд в QTime

Tags: c++, qt, время

Здравствуйте. Есть переменная sec, в ней хранится длинна песни в секундах (к примеру 364). Хотелось бы засунуть эти секунды в обьект класса QTime.

Есть такой код:

```
QTime time(0, 0, 0);
int sec = 364;
time.addSecs(5);
qDebug() << "Length time: " << time.toString("hh:mm:ss");
```

Но оно не работает, увы. Как можно ввести секунды и получить 00:06:04?

Comment: А ничего что ваша "int sec" в приведенном коде не используется? ;-)

Comment: Упс, это я уже пробовал разные варианты. Там, конечно же, time.addSecs(secs);. По прежнему, не работает

Comment: Как именно не работает? QTime time(0, 0, sec) пробовали?

Comment: Да, пробовал конечно.

Comment: Просто он ничего не передает. В отладчике просто напротив time - (invalid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `addSecs` имеет следующее объявление `QTime QTime::addSecs(int s) const`, т.е. она не модифицирует текущий объект, а создаёт новый. В вашем случаи можно поступить так:

```
QTime time = QTime(0,0).addSecs(364);
qDebug() << "Length time: " << time.toString("hh:mm:ss");
```

Добавление аргументов в конструктор `QTime` для часов и минут при этом является обязательным, поскольку в обратном случае объект будет считаться невалидным: `isValid() == false`, и добавление секунд не будет произведено корректно.

Вывод в консоли:

> Length time:  "00:06:04"

Comment: Наверное я особенный. Не работает. Всё так же Length time:  ""

Comment: @alexis031182, не обязательно. Проверьте следующий код: `QTime time_def;
    qDebug() << "time_def.isValid(): " << time_def.isValid();
    qDebug() << "time_def.isNull(): " << time_def.isNull();

    QTime time = QTime().addSecs(364);
    qDebug() << "Length time: " << time.toString("hh:mm:ss");
    qDebug() << "time.isValid(): " << time.isValid();
    qDebug() << "time.isNull(): " << time.isNull();
`

Comment: Спасибо большое. Заработало